# Convert to 3d kml or any render-able file

Tags: angular, cesiumjs

```
viewer.entities.add({
  name: "Dome",
  position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-120.0, 40.0),
  ellipsoid: {
    radii: new Cesium.Cartesian3(200000.0, 200000.0, 200000.0),
    maximumCone: Cesium.Math.PI_OVER_TWO,
    material: Cesium.Color.BLUE.withAlpha(0.3),
    outline: true,
  },
});
```

The code above represents a dome that I intend to upload to Cesium ion in 3D format, with specified height and radius parameters. I’m seeking guidance on how to accomplish this using Angular

I want to make file which is render able on cesium ion. The file should contain the dome which is created with the use of above code